# Elevation (shadow) to Android Widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Has anyone had success adding `android:elevation` to an Android widget (i.e. subclass of AppWidgetProvider) root layout. It seems it is not do-able?

I am developing for Lollipop and `android:elevation` works fine if it is layout within an activity but not in case of a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Elevation didn't work with widget in my case too. I achieved it using **cardview.**

Keep your full stuff of layout inside cardview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_aspectRatio="66%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="75%"
        card:cardElevation="25dp"
        card:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />
```

You could also try to give shadow effect as background drawable instead of cardview. Here you go :

```
<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#00888888" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#10888888" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#20888888" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:bottom="1px" />
        <solid android:color="#30888888" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:bottom="1px" />
        <solid android:color="#50888888" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#50CCCCCC"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: I'm aware of CardView but looking for a solution with using RelativeLayout

Comment: @2cupsOfTech : I updated my answer with drawable which could create shadow effect like elevation or similar to cardview

Comment: the second approach is not a blurry shadow though just a plain color shadow, right?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech : I applied color codes such a way that it would look like bit blurry shadow.

Comment: @2cupsOfTech : Is it ok?

Comment: I don't like the idea of using 5 shapes to draw a shadow

Comment: I don't think CardView can be used in a widget.